# Selenium chrome webDriver - get focus on the latest open new tab java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem while trying to get focus on the latest new tab i'v opened with selenium web driver.

in some mysterious way, when i try to change between 2 tabs it works, 
but when i'm trying to do this with 4 tabs it always get focus on the 3rd tab.

here is the code of the function that gets WebDriver element:

```
ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());
    System.out.println(tabs);
    System.out.println(tabs.get(tabs.size() -1));
    driver.switchTo().window((String) tabs.get(tabs.size() - 1));
```

and here is the out put when i'm printing the tabs:

```
[CDwindow-(43C81B1D7B7C666BFBFB339971ADEE0F), CDwindow-(CDD5D45D021E698DD005BC2AD6201714), CDwindow-(33FB208B51A8DD5F7DB947C7B0BAB9DD), CDwindow-(4B50A8C4074BEDB41152003DED37FB32)]
CDwindow-(4B50A8C4074BEDB41152003DED37FB32)
```

as you can see the first row is the all the ArrayList.
and the second row is only the last tab that i want to get focus on.

am i missing something here??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after a little bit of debugging - i just wrote an if statement the will stop on the page i want.

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String handle : handles) {
     if (!handle.equals(currentHandle)) {
         driver.switchTo().window(handle);
         if(whatImLookingFor)
             break;
     }
   }
```

the problem is solved for me, but i think it worth to try to understand this for future needs...

Comment: You're just looping through all the tabs until you find one that works. This has many disadvantages. 1) What if more than one page can fulfill the if()? 2) If the `whatImLookingFor` doesn't exist, the for loop just goes to the next statement as if it had found it (break gets you out of loop just like completing all the iterations without breaking) so you don't know if you found it or not and can still get errors. 3) You're wasting time by searching every page instead of going to the correct one in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the issue.

`tabs` holds a list of handles (which may or may not be in the order you see them in the browser). 
`tabs.size()` is returning 4 (4 tabs). so `tabs.get(tabs.size() - 1))` is `tabs.get(4 -1 )` or `tabs.get(3)`.

Since java is 0-indexed, `tabs.get(3)` is the last tab. And looking at the output above is correct; **CDwindow-(4B50A8C4074BEDB41152003DED37FB32)**.

Where is it going to the third tab; CDwindow-(33FB208B51A8DD5F7DB947C7B0BAB9DD)?

I find it easier to keep track of if you Map the windows to a name:

```
public static Map<String, String> tabs = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

With the first String being your own descriptor like "Admin", or "Facebook" and the second String is the WindowHandle. You will need to add the windows one by one to keep track of them.

```
tabs.put(handleName, handle);
```

But when you want to switch you can use:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get("Admin"));
```

And eliminate all confusion.

Comment: It has to be in the same order as they got in isn't it?
but that is not the issue because i'v also tried this function:
 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
     String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
     for (String handle : handles) {

      if (!handle.equals(currentHandle))
      {
          driver.switchTo().window(handle);
      }
    } @MivaScott

Comment: @Pikolo, I have found that getWindowHandles() is non-deterministic when it comes to order. In other words, you cannot guarantee the order of your List, Set, etc will be in the same order as you see them on the screen. As such you cannot trust that the third tab in your browser is third in the list. Which I think is causing confusion in your second example. That code is great if you only have two windows as it will always choose the tab you're not currently looking at. But if there are 3 or more it is useless. You **have** to label each tab to know for sure you're switching to the right one